# Sildeshow don't fade on hover when same image

Tags: jquery, slideshow, fade

I have a JQuery slideshow on this webpage http://www.2eenheid.de/cloud/.

1. The page 'Cloud' has its own background image.
2. Hovering on other menu items changes this bg img with a fadeIn and Out
3. But it also happens when hovering on the 'Cloud' menu item. That makes it look messy. It just fades back and forth to the same image. How to remove this in my code? Make it do nothing when the bg img is already the same img.

**JQUERY**

```
    <script type="text/javascript">
    $(function () {
            var imgsrc = '';
            var newImg = '';
            imgsrc = $('.pikachoose').css('background-image');

            $('ul.slideshow-menu').find('a').hover(function () {
                newImg = $(this).attr('src');
                if (imgsrc === newImg) { return; }

                $('.pikachoose').stop().fadeOut('fast', function () {
                    $(this).css({
                        'background-image': 'url(' + newImg + ')'
                    }).fadeTo('slow', 1);
                });



            }, function () {

                $('.pikachoose').stop().fadeOut('fast', function () {
                    $(this).css({
                        'background-image': imgsrc 
                    }).fadeTo('slow', 1);
                });
            });

        }); 
    </script>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you do `imgsrc = $('.pikachoose').css('background-image');`, then `imgsrc` contains the string

`url(http://example.com/image.jpg)` and not

`http://example.com/image.jpg`

Where as `newImg` contains `http://example.com/image.jpg` So the comparison fails.

Try converting `imgsrc` into a proper URL, like this :

```
new_imgsrc=imgsrc.replace(/url\(("|'|)|("|'|)\)/g,'');
```

and then try the `if`

```
if (newImg === new_imgsrc){
    //do something
}
```

Comment: Yes yes yes! It works! But only on Chrome somehow. Any idea why it wont work in IE and Firefox?

Comment: Does this work? `new_imgsrc=imgsrc.replace(/url\(("|'|)|("|'|)\)/g,'');`